# Internet banking regulations in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, internet, finance, banking

I'm writing a report for some University coursework, in which I am supposed to analyse the security of an online bank.

I'm trying, with some difficulty, to find any laws/regulations/standards that apply to online banking in the UK that I could reference. Could someone point me towards any legislation or specific acts/standards that might apply to online banking? The report is mostly focused on the technical security aspects, but it would be nice to briefly mention some law or standard that covers online banking.

So far the only relevant materials I've found apply to the US (e.g. the Electronic Fund Transfer Act 1978), but I'm writing specifically about HSBC in the UK.

Comment: The FCA and the PRA in the UK regulate financial services, but off the top of my head I don't know what specific regulations relate to online banking. Are you primarily concerned with funds transfers?

Comment: @jimsug It's quite general, but I guess it's mostly focused on information security and what they do to minimize risk for customers, if that makes sense. I was mostly looking for a quick reference, since the rest of the report is technical. I think those pointers you gave should be a good starting point though, thank you!

Comment: What it boils down to is that if there is any fraud, either the bank or the user will be held liable. Which it is depends on how the fraud happened. If it's a flaw in the bank's web site, it's them. If the user told someone their password, it's the user.